# I have an issue with my program not resizing the image correctly

Tags: c, cs50

The code is supposed to take 3 arguments and output an image scaled by the specified factor which is between 1 and 100, currently I'm getting an image that doesn't match the expected output.

I'm going to say that the issue is somewhere in the loops, or possibly in the new file sizing.

I get these issues even when the factor is set to 1.

```
// set new height and width of BMP
bi_New.biHeight = bi.biHeight * factor;
bi_New.biWidth = bi.biWidth * factor;

// calculate padding for old file and new file
int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
int padding_New = (4 - (bi_New.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// set the file size for the new file
bf_New.bfSize = 54 + (bi_New.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding_New) * abs(bi_New.biHeight);
bi_New.biSizeImage = bf_New.bfSize - 54;


// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf_New, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&bi_New, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
        // intialise counter to print rows by amount of the factor
        int counter = 0;

        // while loop to keep continuing until factor is less than or equal to counter
        while (counter < factor)
            {
            // iterate over pixels in scanline
            for(int k = 0; k < bi.biWidth; k++)
                {
                // temporary storage
                RGBTRIPLE triple;

                // declare pixel counter
                int pixel_counter = 0;

                // read RGB triple from infile
                fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                // write RGB triple to outfile and use a while loop to iterate the same pixel by factor times
                while (pixel_counter < factor)
                    {
                    fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
                    pixel_counter++;
                    }
                }
            // add new padding
            for (int l = 0; l < padding_New; l++)
                {
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
                }

            // seek back to the beginning of row in input file, but not after iteration of printing
            if (counter < (factor - 1))
                {
                fseek(inptr, -(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)), SEEK_CUR);
                }
            counter++;
            }
        }

    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

// close infile
fclose(inptr);

// close outfile
fclose(outptr);

// success
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use for loops instead of those whiles. Easier to read

Comment: [mcve] i.e. the entire program required. And does the resulting BMP image open - if so then you should convert the image to PNG and add it to then question.

Comment: Please describe the issues. Is the image generated at all? Is it distorted? Wrong size? What information do you get about the image when you open it with another viewer (e.g. IrfanView)? Does the code even compile?

Comment: Please enable all warnings in the compiler and correct everything reported. Also, it would be nice to provide at least the function declaration with its parameters.

Comment: What are the actual values of the biClrUsed and biBitCount field in your file's BITMAPINFOHEADER?

Answer (score 0):

The `j` loop is the culprit. The program will process each scanline `width * factor` times instead of `factor` times. It adds an extra `width` iterations to each scanline.